# Putty is offline. need to automate the " pressing" of the the escape key to connect

Tags: putty

I am using a batch file to open Putty with a saved session called test, which is a serial connection.
    putty.exe -load test

normal conditions: once the session is opened it is offline. It needs the escape key pressed to connect.

I would like to automate this step - the escape key being pressed. I have tried 
    putty.exe -load test ^,  with ^ being the escape key.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`putty.exe -load test ^` won't load and connect any session ...

this works pretty simple (just successfully connected like that on Linux):

```
putty.exe -load "test"
```

Comment: I am in windows environment. The session "test" loads with or without hyphens. In normal settings, When I load the session, it opens and remains offline until I press escape. I would like to send the escape over to putty without  physically pressing it from the keyboard. is this possible?

Comment: @mera try something alike `commands.bat | plink -load "test"` ...see https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage-batch

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The putty session is connected to a hardware that needs to talk to a microprocessor, and it is waiting for the escape key to show its contents on putty..

Comment: @mera probably this would also work: `plink.exe -load "test" < "^"` or `plink.exe -load "test" < commands.bat > console.log` ...one can pipe the I/O into both directions. please consider accepting the answer if it helps.

Comment: It still does not work. I will work on it more and keep you updated.

Comment: @mera in batch, VBScript SendKeys might come handy, because batch cannot send key-stokes. something alike `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{ESC}");`

Comment: I am going to rethink the whole process over. I don't think it is possible the way i am doing it. Thanks!!

Comment: @mera with `Sendkeys` this is entirely possible; with batch there is no chance. `SendKeys` could even be used to automate a `putty` window directly. or use the Linux sub-system of Windows 10 - which would make scripting `plink` easier; because sending keys is rather dramatic on Windows.